# calling operator[] on an c++ array with parameter that could invalidate the address?

Tags: c++, vector, inline, undefined-behavior

I have an std::vector-like class (actually TArray from Unreal Engine) that has a function "AddDefaulted" which adds an element and returns the *index* as integer to the newly added element. It also has an operator as member-function that returns.. well.. the element at that index. Simplified something like that:

```
template<class T> struct TArray
{
    // omitted initialization and typical std::vector-like implementation stuff..
    T* data;
    T* GetData() { return data; }
    int AddDefaulted() { /* might change "data" if array grows */ }
    T& operator[](int i) { return GetData()[i]; }
}
```

Now I stumbled upon a call to the operator[] and AddDefault in one expression:

```
TArray<X> a = ...;
X& x = a[a.AddDefaulted()];
```

Well, it looks unsuspicious, but I wonder.. could that be illegal? My thinking is: Could the compiler inline operator[] and then first evaluate the data pointer and then evaluate AddDefaulted and so accessing the "old" data array?

Comment: No, `a.AddDefaulted()` will be evaluated first and the result will be passed to `a.operator[](int)`

Comment: I don't think the compiler can perform such an optimization on non-trivial types, since `AddDefaulted` is a non-const method.  That's just a gut feel though, so take this with a grain of salt.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yea, I thought so too.. So inlining the operator call doesn't affect that at all, right? (in the code here, its even declared with __forceinline).

Comment: @Imi - No it doesn't. Optimizations must still respect the behavior of valid code.

Comment: ..and out of curiosity: Would it change anything, if operator[] would be a global free function "T& operator[](TArray<T>& a, int i) { return a.GetData()[i]; }" instead? Could an aggressive-inlining compiler actually first resolve the complete GetData() before it evaluates whatever is passed as index (aka call AddDefaulted) ?

Comment: Even if the name is `__forceinline` it's still just a hint. If it can't do the inlining without noticeable side effects, it should skip the inlining. I would recommend _never_ using `__forceinline` without measuring the effect though. "_The `__forceinline` keyword overrides the cost/benefit analysis and relies on the judgment of the programmer instead._"

Comment: That's what I thought you were asking in the first place, and the tentative answer is such an aggressive optimization shouldn't happen because a non-const method can change the underlying object.  The whole thing still looks suspicious though, and is not a nice design.  I'd be more concerned about whether these calls are actually part of the same sequence point, which could potentially be a UB thing.

Comment: @paddy hm.. I thought only "writing to the same memory twice within a single expression" is bad, but calling non-const functions is fine. Here, only AddDefaulted is ever writing anything to memory, so I tought its fine? (If even writing and reading the same memory location within one expression would be problem, wouldn't that even affect things like "i = i + 1"?)

Comment: From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order): _When calling a function (**whether or not the function is inline**, and whether or not explicit function call syntax is used), **every value computation and side effect associated with any argument expression**, or with the postfix expression designating the called function, **is sequenced before execution of every expression or statement in the body of the called function**._ Generally, optimizations cannot change the effect of the code (with some known exceptions such as copy elision).

Comment: @TedLyngmo Good recommendation! I hope Epic did their research in the Unreal Engine.. ;)

Comment: @Imi :-) I'm sure they did - but still. Using `__forceinline` instead of `inline` probably requires re-testing the inlining effect whenever something in the code changes that can have an effect on that part of the code.

Comment: mh.. I guess that line could still be made illegal, if the operator[] was global or static and taking a T* as first parameter and TArray has an implicit conversion operator into T*... ;-) But it is not and it has not, so thanks to you all: I am now sufficiently convinced that the code is fine.

Comment: What does `AddDefaulted()` do if it attempts to change "data" and fails in the attempt?   If it throws an exception, there is no problem (except, if the exception is never caught, in which case the program will terminate).   If it can return a bad index, that needs to be checked for before passing the return value to `operator[]()`, not after.

Comment: It can be made bad/illegal by the programmer but as @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica mentioned optimizations aren't allowed to make otherwise valid code invalid (unless one counts `-ffast-math` -like optimizations which deliberately turns off compliance with the standard).